# SKmaps callout not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

Hi i had added `Annotations` from an `NSArray` and added them successfully in the map, and on `didselectannotation` method i had created a callout view which contains a `UIButton`, on clicking the `UIButton` the navigation is performed to a `detailViewController`, everything works for the first time, but when i return from `detailview` to `mapview`, i am able to select annotation, but the call out view is not popping out. but mapView `calloutViewForAnnotation`: method is called bot the call out is not appearing . please help

Comment: We need code for methods "didLoad" "willAppear" "didAppear"

Comment: now its kind of fixed. i changed my map initializing code from viewdidload to view will appear... it worked... thanks a lot

Comment: @Mohanraj- please add the solution as an answer and after that mark it as solved